# SQL Server Job Failure Notifications on Set Intervals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server job that sends out a notification every time it fails.  I run this job every 5 minutes.  If something the job needs has its state changed at 10:00 PM at night and the problem isn't discovered until the next morning, there would be over 100 e-mails sent with the same failure notification.

Is there anyway for you to throttle the number of e-mails sent?  For example, I would like SQL Server to send out an e-mail notification on the hour if any of the 12 scheduled runs during the hour fails, but no more than one e-mail should be sent (even if there are multiple failures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a simple table with the job name and a `bit` column indicating whether an email has been sent successfully, then check that column as part of the alert.

```
DECLARE Notifications TABLE
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    JobName varchar(50),
    MailSent bit DEFAULT 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS select Database Mail under Management, right-click and Configure Database Mail. After that's complete send a test mail using the new profile to confirm that works.

Next, open the properties of the SQL Server Agent. On the Alert System page enable the mail profile. Restart the SQL Server Agent for the change to take effect.

Under the SQL Server agent create Operators to send messages to.

Finally, in your job select Notifications and set the Operator to send to when the job completes.

Comment: It looks like OP already has the mail functionality working, they just want to send *less* emails. Your post doesn't answer the question.